# Postgres - best design for recording up to 8000 ints?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

Newbie to postgres here - so I have a corpus of 8000+ documents (each labelled with a number/index), and I'm trying to create a table in which each row is for a single word and will record the index of each document in which it is mentioned. My primary goal is to be able to get the list of document IDs that each word is mentioned in.

I've thought of using an array, or a long binary string, but none of those seem like great solutions. Someone suggested to me that I make another table for each term, but considering that I'd have quite a few terms, I feel like that'd be rather memory intensive also.

What's the best way, if any, to accomplish this?

Comment: You might be interested in full text search:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/textsearch.html.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, I'd be looking at the following schema to start with:

```
words:
    id        integer type, auto-increment, primary key, indexed
    word      varchar(something), unique constraint, indexed
documents:
    id        integer type, auto-increment, primary key, indexed
    details   whatever is needed
words_in_document:
    word_id   integer type, foreign key to words(id)
    doc_id    integer type, foreign key to documents(id)
              primary key on word_id, doc_id
              possible second index on doc_id, word_id
```

That's the standard way of efficiently representing a many-to-many relationship.

I wouldn't be *too* concerned about 8,000 documents or even millions of words, that's what databases are built for. In some shops, 8,000 rows would be considered a small configuration table.

---

With that schema, finding a list of documents containing a given word would be something like:

```
select d.details
from   documents d,
       words w,
       words_in_document wid
where  w.word = 'desired_word'
  and  w.id = wid.word_id
  and  d.id = wid.doc_id
```

(that's the implicit join syntax, there's also an explicit join variant as well).

Comment: Okay, so then what type of query would I make in order to get the list of documents that contains a given word?

Comment: @cakesofwrath, that would be something like  `select d.details from documents d, words w, words_in_document wid where w.word = 'desired_word' and w.id = wid.word_id and d.id = wid.doc_id` (or its equivalent explicit join method). I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing an [*inverse index*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

In its simplest form, you'll need:

```
create table document (id int primary key, name text);
create table word (id int, document_id int references document, word text);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5cb05)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Full Text Search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html), which is a standard feature of PostgreSQL with full support (and then some) for everything that you want.

In particular, it has built-in solutions for issues such as common words of no interest ("and", "or", "the", "an", etc), verb forms ("am", "is", "are" for "to be", for instance), capitalization, synonyms ("1", "one", for example), plurals, etc etc etc.

It may be a bit of a hassle to set it up to focus on the words of interest, but you'd have similar issues (and many more) with a manual solution.